# Fecha actual con JavaScript amarrandolo al active de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen día, espero y me puedan ayudar, estoy haciendo una pagina web HTML y Javascript, en un apartado estoy haciendo cumpleaños de compañeros por meses, Bootstrap maneja los apartado "Active", busco en javascript que al obtener la fecha actual el active haga referencia a esa fecha, no se si se pueda o hay alguna forma de hacerlo

```js
 <script language="JavaScript">
               window.onload = function() {
                   var fecha = new Date(); //Fecha actual
                   var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1; //obteniendo mes
                   var dia = fecha.getDate(); //obteniendo dia
                   var ano = fecha.getFullYear(); //obteniendo año
                   if (dia < 10)
                       dia = '0' + dia; //agrega cero si el menor de 10
                   if (mes < 10)
                       mes = '0' + mes //agrega cero si el menor de 10
                   document.getElementById('fechaActual').value = ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
               }
           </script>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 ml-auto mr-auto">
            <div class="profile-tabs">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-icons justify-content-center" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="fechaActual" href="#enero" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Enero
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#febrero" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Febrero
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#marzo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Marzo
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#abril" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Abril
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#mayo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Mayo
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#junio" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Junio
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

imagen de como busco hacerlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo que pretendes. ¿Qué haz intentado? Aquí en la comunidad, funciona mucho mejor si haces tu el trabajo y aquí te apoyamos a pulir. Difícilmente alguien te lo hará de cero.

Comment: Eh intentado con javascript obtener la fecha, lo cual ya hice, ahora lo que pretendo es que cuando un usuario entre al apartado de cumpleaños aparezca el "nav active" con el mes actual.

Adjunto imagen para ver mas o menos lo que busco

Comment: Hola, agrega el código que has intentado a la pregunta por favor.

Comment: listo @the-breaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes poner un id a los nav links de la siguiente forma:

```
<a id="mes0" class="nav-link" href="#enero" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
  <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Enero
</a>
```

Y luego con javascript lo buscas en el documento y añades active al classList

```
var actualMonth = new Date().getMonth();
var monthLink = document.getElementById("mes"+actualMonth);
monthLink.classList.add("active");
```

Funcionando:

```js
var actualMonth = new Date().getMonth();
var monthLink = document.getElementById("mes"+actualMonth);
monthLink.classList.add("active");
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
a {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<a id="mes7" class="nav-link" href="#agosto" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
  <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Agosto
</a>
<a id="mes8" class="nav-link" href="#septiembre" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
  <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Septiembre
</a>
<a id="mes9" class="nav-link" href="#octubre" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
  <i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> Octube
</a>
```

Afortunadamente tu código sólo correrá una vez al inicio, por lo que es sencillo. Ir actualizando conforme se seleccione otra opción es una pregunta distinta ;)

Comment: muchas gracias @Juan_De_la_Cruz me has ayudado mucho

Comment: Si resolvió tu duda, puedes marcarla como la respuesta 

Comment: disculpa, tengo otra duda, lo que pasa es que ya se selecciona el tab solo que ahora no me muestra la información que tiene, hay alguna función para que abra el tab seleccionado

Comment: Eso es un asunto completamente distinto. Lo ideal sería que hicieses otra pregunta pero trata de reducir tu duda a algo más específico; con los detalles que diste no es suficiente para saber como ayudarte.